# mouseover, mouseout, se aplica a todos los items

Tags: jquery, imagen

Estoy haciendo un `mouseover` y `mouseout` a unas imagenes que tienen la misma clase. Les quiero poner un `visibility: hidden` y `visibility: visible`. El código que dejo lo hace pero lo aplica a todo los elementos al mismo tiempo.

¿Como hago para que se aplique a cada elemento individual o en si mismo?

Gracias.

```js
$(".vc_clearfix", this).mouseover(function(){
      $('.vc_gitem-zone-img').css("visibility", "hidden");
     });
   $(".vc_clearfix", this).mouseout(function(){
      $('.vc_gitem-zone-img').css("visibility", "visible");
    });
```

Comment: El codigo que tienes le aplica la visibilidad a todos los elementos que tienen la clase `.vc_gitem-zone-img`. No es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: si pero uno por uno, no todos al miso tiempo.

Comment: Deberias de especificar eso en tu respuesta.

Comment: imagina que es una grilla de imágenes, y tienes la opacidad en 100% quiero mostrar y ocultar esa opacidad por cada item, a hora lo muestra a todas a la vez

Comment: Podrías agregar el código HTML de un par de imágenes de muestra para ayudar a visualizar mejor la respuesta? Sobre todo para saber el acomodo de tus clases.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que la clase en común es vc_clearfix, sólo tendrías que señalar el hijo del elemento sobre el que pasas el ratón (vc_clearfix) mediante la clase por ejemplo.

```js
$(".vc_clearfix", this).mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('.vc_gitem-zone-img').css("visibility", "hidden");
});
$(".vc_clearfix", this).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).children('.vc_gitem-zone-img').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una clase en específico para los elementos que quieres y agregarla al selector de jquery que estas usando.

Ejemplo basico de selectores de jQuery:

```
$('#ID.vc_clearfix')
```

Con el # buscarias por el **ID** del elemento

```
$('.vc_clearfix.otra_clase')
```

También puedes concatenar las **clases** para ser mas especifico, o agregarle tu clase a los elementos que quieres modificar.

```
$('div.vc_clearfix')
```

En este caso a todos los **DIV** con la clase .vc_clearfix se les ejecutara el método que mencionas.

Aquí hay información y esta en español con la que te puedes apoyar:
[Selectores de jQuery](http://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-selectors-selectores-4768/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un identificador y luego afectar solo a las imágenes de ese ID

```
$("#ID").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').css("visibility", "hidden");
});

$("#ID").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('img').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```